# no me abre la funcion alguna sugerencia? :c

Tags: python, tkinter, txt

```
def mayor(lista):
    if(len(lista)==1):
        return (lista[0])
    
    else:
        Mayor=mayor(lista[1:])
        
        if(lista[0]>Mayor):
            return(lista[0])
        else:
            return Mayor
    try:
        datos=open("ventas.txt","r")
        datos2=open("vendedores.txt","r")
        l_ruts=[]
        l_nombres=[]
        l_apellidos=[]
        l_dia=[]
        for linea2 in datos2:
            lista=linea2.split()
            l_ruts.append(lista[0])
            l_nombres.append(lista[1])
            l_apellidos.append(lista[2])
            lista_max=[]
        for linea in datos:
            lista=linea.split()
            x=(int(lista[1]),int(lista[2]),int(lista[3]),int(lista[4]),int(lista[5]),int(lista[6]),int(lista[7]))
    # funcion recursiva
            lista_max.append(mayor(x))

            l_dia.append(x.index(mayor(x)))
            
    finally:
        datos.close()
    
    etiqueta=Label(marco3,text="Seleccione el rut del trabajador para mostar su mayor monto vendido y sus datos").place(x=20,y=20)
    rut_buscar=StringVar()
    rut_tra=ttk.Combobox(marco3,values=l_ruts,textvariable=rut_buscar).place(x=20,y=100)
```

tengo un problema con mi codigo, cuando abro el tkinter no me abre la funcion :C no se si sera por mala identacion o por que hice algo mal, intente cambiar algunas variables y aun asi no me abre la funcion , corriganme porfis, si necesitan el codigo entero me avisan

Comment: A que te referis con "no me abre la función"? Si yo pongo los imports necesarios, voy a ejecutar tu código y tener el mismo error? Te recomiendo ser mas claro.

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que tienes que desplazar todo el código a la izquierda desde el try, sino sigues estando dentro de la función "mayor".

No hay mucha información ni se sabe la finalidad de esto.

¿Quizás quieres conseguir algo así?

```
try:
    l_ruts = []
    l_nombres = []
    l_apellidos = []
    l_dia = []
    lista_max = []

    with open("vendedores.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as datos2:
        for linea2 in datos2:
            lista = linea2.split()
            try:
                l_ruts.append(lista[0])
                l_nombres.append(lista[1])
                l_apellidos.append(lista[2])
            except IndexError:
                print('Faltan datos en el archivo vendedores.txt')

    with open("ventas.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as datos:
        for linea in datos:
            lista = linea.split()
            x = []
            for i in range(1, 7):
                try:
                    x.append(lista[i])
                except IndexError:
                    print('Faltan datos en el archivo ventas.txt')
                except ValueError:
                    print('Error en los datos en el archivo ventas.txt, no todos los valores son int')

            # No hay que crear ninguna función para comprobar el valor más mayor, usemos "max()
            lista_max.append(max(x))
            l_dia.append(x.index(max(x)))

    # No se la finalidad de todo esto. Vamos a printarlo
    for i in range(0, len(l_ruts)):
        print(f'l_ruts es {l_ruts[i]}. El señor {l_nombres[i]} {l_apellidos[i]}.')
    for i in range(0, len(lista_max)):
        print(f'Venta {i}. El máximo es de {lista_max[i]} en el día {l_dia[i]}.')

except (FileNotFoundError, PermissionError, OSError) as e:
    print(f'Algo ha fallado con algún fichero: {e}')
```

Comentarios:

- No veo ninguna ventaja en crear la función "mayor", para esot tenemos "max()": [Info sobre max()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/max)
- Es recomentadble utilizar with al abrir ficheros, nos ahorramos tener que cerrar el fichero: [Formas de abrir ficheros](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/file-operation)
- No se la finalidad de todo esto, simplemente lo he printado.
- Trata de añadir excepciones específicas para error concreto, el código es de mucha mayor calidad, claridad y de esta forma se definen claramente el tipo de error. Y es una forma de aprender además.

Está testeado para cuando los ficheros sean los siguientes:

vendedores.txt:

```
123 Paco Fernandez
321 Pepe Perez
```

ventas.txt:

```
Paco 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Pepe 2 8 3 4 5 6 7
```

Siendo el output el siguiente:

```
l_ruts es 123. El señor Paco Fernandez.
l_ruts es 321. El señor Pepe Perez.
Venta 0. El máximo es de 6 en el día 5.
Venta 1. El máximo es de 8 en el día 1.
```